# Can’t use android:xlargeScreens="true"?

Tags: android, manifest, tablet, screen-size

I am making app for phones, but I wan’t them to be usable on tablets. I don’t know why can’t. I use this in my android manifest file:

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

I get this error:

***error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'***

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="cro.perger.bonbon"
      android:versionCode="5"
      android:versionName="1.4">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".bonbon"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <!-- Broadcast Receiver that will process AppWidget updates -->
        <receiver android:name=".HelloWidget" android:label="@string/w_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>    

        </application>
        <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
</manifest>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to build different APKs for older and new versions.  Checkout out the blog posted on http://android-developers.blogspot.com/search/label/Android%20Market about multiple APK support: "Multiple APK support gives you a variety of ways to control app distribution. For example, you could use it to create separate APKs for phones and tablets under the same product listing."

Answer (score 12):

Please check your **project Build Target** To support xlarge screen your project build target should be atleast android 2.3.3 adk.

In Eclipse -?right click on project -> Properties -> Android -> Select Project Build Tagrget as 2.3.3 or onwards

Comment: Is this mean, that my app wont be usable on android devices with android 1.6, 2.1 and 2.2 ??

Comment: yes. The app wont be usable on on android devices with android 1.6, 2.1 and 2.2

Comment: Ok, then how can i Make my app work on phones and tablets ?? because on the publish site on the market, Tablets are not in supported devices ??

Comment: It will be usable on lower API Levels as long as you set `minSdkVersion` to a correct value (like 4 for 1.6 or 7 for 2.1).

Comment: @SunilKumarSahoo I didn't see this warning, till i update adt to 23 and eclipse to 4.x! In past i set xlargeScreen=true and minSdkversion=8 with any error.

Answer (score 6):

My application supports android versions 1.5 to the latest version and this is what I have in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

This is what shows up on the android market developer site for my app:

```
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
        android.hardware.touchscreen
This application is available to over 555 devices.
```

Also, my project build target is 2.3.3, but I still have many installs on devices running android 3.0

And this is just a guess, im not sure about this, but wouldn't including permissions like CALL_PHONE filter your application from search on a tablet since they dont have that feature?

Comment: Ok, and how about premission SEND_SMS ??

Comment: I think problem that my app istn shoving more than 469 devices is that I use a android.hardware.telephony ... But can it be removed and my app still can send SMS ??

Comment: I dont know what you're app does, but i think you have to remove the part of your app that deals with calling and sending sms, since tablets dont have those features.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use at least android API Level 9 for `android:xlargeScreens` to be recognized in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For this make sure in your `default.properties` file you have `target=android-9` or higher. This also can be set using Project Properties, in Android section.

Comment: I didn't see this warning, till i update adt to 23 and eclipse to 4.x! in past i set xlargeScreen=true and minSdkversion=8.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `minSdkVersion`.

The `xlargeScreens`-attribute was introduced in API-Level 9. Since you specified that your application will probably run under API-Level 4, android can't find this attribute.

Change the `minSdkVersion`-attribute to `11` and it should work.

The `targetSdkVersion`-attribute, which you set to be `11` only indicates that the App was developed to target this version (so it's "recommended"), but the `minSdkVersion` specifies the minimum API-Level, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: But then my app wont be usable on android phones with 2.1 and 2.2 android version ?? or am I wrong ??

Comment: Ok, then how can i Make my app work on phones and tablets ?? because on the publish site on the market, Tablets are not in supported devices ??

Comment: The App will work on tablets even if you don't declare the `xlargeScreens`-attribute. And if you used proper layouts, it will look good on them, too. This attribute was only added for the ["Screen Compatibility Mode"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)

Comment: But, on market my app isn't showing for tablets. and i tried to install, but it say that it is not compatibile :(

Comment: Can you copy the APK-file on the memory-card and install it from there?

Comment: dont'know, I don't have a tablet in my posesion :( i will try and write result here...

Comment: Ok, now i can install an app on tablet, but on market, still says Flyer and other tablets are not supported :( And i tried to put multiple app, and second app has removed premission MAKE_CALL

Answer (score 1):

What is your API level set to? It says in the documentation that it requires API 9 or higher. 9 is 2.3. See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) link which says:

> android:xlargeScreens Indicates whether the application supports extra
>   large screen form-factors. An xlarge screen is defined as a screen
>   that is significantly larger than a "large" screen, such as a tablet
>   (or something larger) and may require special care on the
>   application's part to make good use of it, though it may rely on
>   resizing by the system to fill the screen. The default value for this
>   actually varies between some versions, so it's better if you
>   explicitly declare this attribute at all times. Beware that setting it
>   "false" will generally enable screen compatibility mode. This
>   attribute was introduced in API level 9.

Answer (score 1):

[**android:xlargeScreens :**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge) 
This attribute was introduced in *API level 9 (Android 2.3.3)*. If you have your build target lesser than API level 9, then you will get error `"No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android"`
Set your build target to *API level 9* or above and this error will vanish.