# Screen limitations in 2.2

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

I need to limit my app to only run on screen small, medium and large screens but not xlarge. I can't write it in the manifest since the build is on 2.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984488/cant-use-androidxlargescreens-true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to do anything in the manifest file. The `xlarge` tag was introduced in Android 2.3, so it won't be relevant in your case.

**Updated**
If you want to make sure that xlarge devices can't use it, you should put this in your application manifest file and change the target API to level 9 (Android 2.3, in which the tag was introduced) and the minimum SDK level to something lower, i.e. 8 for Android 2.2.

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: I've got a bunch of tablets here who think otherwise :( They seem to download, install and run the app just fine.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you mean then. Please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: @Michell Bak: Your `<support-screens>` says that the app *only* works on `xlarge`, which is the inverse of what the OP requests.

Comment: Sorry, I just copied it from an app of my own, and forgot to change it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`<compatible-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html), such as:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

> I can't write it in the manifest since the build is on 2.2.

You act as though you have a choice. You do not. Change your project's build target to API Level 9.