# Jquery-Mobile: it does not support the android:xlargescreen tag

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to jquery mobile framework. I creating the small application in android using phonegap jquery mobile.After creating the app in eclipse using phonegap icon. It shows an error in the android manifeast file. The error is No resource identifier found for attribute 'xlargeScreens' in package 'android'. why it cames? How can i handle this. is jquery mobile does not support xlarge screens?please can anybody help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with JQueryMobile nor PhoneGap, but rather with the Android Manifest file (which is what defines what this app can do / allowed to access / etc...)

Check out this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984488/cant-use-androidxlargescreens-true) regarding how to fix yours.

Hope this helps